# Download PDF file on Firefox with protractor doesn't work

Tags: angular, firefox, protractor, e2e-testing

I have a problem in my angular 5 e2e tests where I need to automatically download an pdf with firefox. It should not show the "Save as.." window in firefox.

I have already tried some solutions here from stackoverflow, but they don't seem to work for me.

Here is the content of my  protractor.conf.js file:

```
const { SpecReporter } = require('jasmine-spec-reporter');

exports.config = {
  allScriptsTimeout: 11000,
  specs: [
    './e2e/**/*.e2e-spec.ts'
  ],
  capabilities: {
    'browserName' : 'firefox',
    'moz:firefoxOptions': {
      prefs: {
        'browser.download.folderList': 2,
        'browser.download.dir' : process.cwd() + "/resources/test/download",
        'services.sync.prefs.sync.browser.download.useDownloadDir': true,
        'browser.download.useDownloadDir': true,
        'browser.download.manager.alertOnEXEOpen': false,
        'browser.download.manager.closeWhenDone': true,
        'browser.download.manager.focusWhenStarting': false,
        'browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting': false,
        'browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force': false,
        'browser.download.manager.showAlertOnComplete': false,
        'browser.download.manager.useWindow': false,
        'browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk': 'application/pdf',
      },
    },
  },
  directConnect: true,
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4200/',
  framework: 'jasmine',
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000,
    print: function() {}
  },
  onPrepare() {
    require('ts-node').register({
      project: 'e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json'
    });
    require("zone.js/dist/zone-node");
    require("zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone");
    require("zone.js/dist/async-test");
    require("zone.js/dist/fake-async-test");
    require("zone.js/dist/sync-test");
    require("zone.js/dist/proxy");
    require("zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch");
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({ spec: { displayStacktrace: true } }));
  }
};
```

But when in the protractor test, the download pdf Button is clicked, firefox still opens the "Save as..." prompt and it does not automatically download the pdf.
However it creates the "/resources/test/download" folder during the test. But it is empty.

I am using Firefox Version 66.0.2 on Mac OS Mojave (10.14.4) and in package.json:

```
"selenium-webdriver": "^4.0.0-alpha.1",
"jasmine-core": "2.99.1",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
"karma": "~2.0.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
"karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~1.4.1",
"karma-firefox-launcher": "^1.1.0",
"karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~0.2.2",
"protractor": "~5.4.0",
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you verify the MIME type of your file with the network inspector? Make sure it isn't something like 'application/octet-stream' instead. The value in 'browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk' needs to match the content type exactly.

Comment: According to the Header of the Response which looks like this:
`HTTP/1.1 200 OK
x-powered-by: Express
access-control-allow-origin: *
content-type: application/json
date: Mon, 08 Apr 2019 19:12:14 GMT
connection: close
transfer-encoding: chunked`
The MIME type should be `application/json`but when change the Value to `'browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk': 'application/json' `the "Save as.." window in firefox still opens and the file ist not getting downloaded.

Comment: The angular/typescript code, that triggers the GET request looks like this: `this.http.get(http://localhost:4200/getPdf, {responseType: 'blob'}).subscribe((file: Blob) => {   FileSaver.saveAs(file, this.fileBaseName +  '_V1.pdf'); …`

Comment: I just deleted the download folder `/resources/test/download` and ran the e2e Test again. During the test Protractor creates the `/resources/test/download` folder correctly, the firefox download window opens, and for a short period I can see a File in the folder that looks like this `6xcvK+Le.pdf.part`. But after the test finishes the file disappears again.

Comment: Can you try using 'application/octet-stream'? I skimmed the source code of FileSaver.js and it looks like that might be setting the content type. Also found a reference to that here: https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/issues/180